# Yii2 - compress cookie value or better alternative

Tags: php, yii2

I am dealing with a existing code which stores the order item details in a cookie.

in Controller:

```
public function actionAdd2cart($id, $url, $instructor_id, $location_id, $start_time, $date1) {
    $ep = Yii::$app->getTable->settings('general','enable_payment');
   $order_item = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('order_item');
        {
    $model = ClassDuration::find()->where(['id' => $id])->One();
    $model1 = Instructor::find()->where(['user_id' => $instructor_id])->One();
    $time = strtotime($start_time);
    $duration = $model1['instructor_duration'];
    $endTime = date("h:i A", strtotime('+' . $duration . ' minutes', $time));
    $fees = Instructor::find()->where(['user_id' => $model['instructor_id']])->one();                 
    $order_item[] = [
        'duration' => date('h:i A', strtotime($start_time)) . '-' . $endTime,                                
        'starttime' => $start_time,
        'endtime' => $endTime,
        'id' => $model->id,
        //'price' => $fees['instructor_fees'], this is disabled as payment info is not needed and to increase the cookie size
        'q' => 1,
        'date' => $model->start_date,
        'instructor_id' => $instructor_id,
        'location_id' => $location_id,
        'date1' => $date1,
        'datetime' => $date1 . "-" . $start_time . "i" . $instructor_id,
        ]; //product details array
                }

/********** cookies for product details **********/

        $cookie = new \yii\web\Cookie([
            'name' => 'order_item',
            'value' => $order_item,
            'expire' => time() + (60 * 60 * 24),
        ]);
    Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie); // add product deatils to cookies
        if ($url == 'view') {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        } else {
            // echo 1;
        }
    }
```

Now the problem I am facing with this code is like while adding the item to cart, it allow for 6-8 items being added in the cart depending on diffrent browser and due to cookie size limitation, I am not able to add more items to cart beyond that.

I am looking for a way like if the cookie value can be compressed before setting the cookies and uncompressed while accessing it.

or some other suitable solution.

Comment: maybe store the items in your server and the cookie should contain a key unique to that list, or just use sessions.

Comment: Hi Mehi - do you mean I can use - ` $session = new \yii\web\Session...` instead of  `$cookie = new \yii\web\Cookie([` and do I need to rework the code to fit it for session?

Comment: I mean instead of storing the items in a cookie store them in a session.